# How do I install the Perl module File::HomeDir on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, perl, pacman

I need to install the Perl module `File::HomeDir` on a laptop running Arch Linux.

In order to find out which (pacman-)package contains that module, I run

```
pkgfile -u
pkgfile HomeDir.pm
```

The second command, which I believe should indicate which package I need to install, prints nothing.

Does that mean that there is no package with the specific Perl module? Or is there another way to find which package I need to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don_crissti noted in the comments:

> It's not available from the repos, [only from AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/perl-file-homedir/).

Comment: Would it be hurtful if I installed the module "directly" (`cpan install File::HomeDir`) instead of going the extra route to AUR?

Comment: Seems to me that it would work, but I'm not an Arch user myself. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Perl_package_guidelines has some background. Sounds like using AUR may enable pacman to be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

It was added to the community repo.

You can now install it with a simple

```
pacman -S perl-file-homedir
```

See https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-file-homedir/